# how to calculate distance between two points using skobbler maps in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, maps

In google maps we can use distanceTo calculate distance
I dont know how to do in skobbler maps

```
- (void)positionerService:(SKPositionerService *)positionerService updatedCurrentLocation:(CLLocation *)currentLocation;
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at the documentation?  Here, for instance?  http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/android//com/skobbler/ngx/util/SKGeoUtils.html

Comment: What is the purpose of the quoted code?

Answer (score 0):

If my memory doesn't go wrong, there is a property **currentCoordinate** for positionService. Therefore, distance can be calculated like this:

```
    CLLocation *skLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:positionService.currentCoordinate.latitude longitude:positionService.currentCoordinate.longitude];
    CLLocationDistance distance = [currentLocation distanceFromLocation:skLocation];
```